# onResume function not called after I remove the notification menu

Tags: android, gps

I am learning Android app development and I try a lot of things.

Now I'm trying to tell the users if their GPS is turned on on or off. It works fine in all cases even when I move to another app and comes back to my activity. The problem is when I pull down the notification bar and change the setting of GPS from the notification bar on the phone, it seems that onResume() is not called when I come back to my activity.

```
protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if(gpsEnabled){
            int message = new Integer(R.string.enabled);
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText(message);
            textView.setTextSize(20);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            setContentView(textView);
        }
        else{
            int message = new Integer(R.string.disabled);
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText(message);
            textView.setTextSize(20);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            setContentView(textView);
        }
    }
```

This code is the same for onStart() and onCreate(). It works fine except when I pull down the phone's notification menu and change the GPS from there and come back to my activity which was at the background but still visible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to catch the notification center pull event, but you can implement `LocationListener` and listen for `onProviderEnabled` and `onProviderDisabled` events in your case.